# Read Image file metadata

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp.net, image

I want to upload an image file and then extract its basic information (author, dimensions, date created, modified, etc) and display it to the user. How can I do it.

A solution or reference to this problem in asp.net c# code would be helpful. But javascript or php would be ok as well.

Comment: I think GD and imagick extensions in PHP can read EXIF data. The same for other languages.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [Link](http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=160880&page=1). You will get more Clearance about GetDetailsOf() and its File Properties based on the Win-OS version wise.

If you want to use C# code use below code to get Metadata's:

```
List<string> arrHeaders = new List<string>();

 Shell shell = new ShellClass();
 Folder rFolder = shell.NameSpace(_rootPath);
 FolderItem rFiles = rFolder.ParseName(filename);

 for (int i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
 {
      string value = rFolder.GetDetailsOf(rFiles, i).Trim();
      arrHeaders.Add(value);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(fileName);
PropertyItem[] propItems = image.PropertyItems;

foreach (PropertyItem item in propItems)
{
  Console.WriteLine("iD: 0x" + item.Id.ToString("x"));
}
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems.aspx)

[C# Tutorial Reference](http://seecsharp.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-read-image-metadata-in-c.html)

Answer (score 0):

C# solution could be found here:
[Link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7.aspx)
[Link2](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231165-how-to-read-image-metadata-in-c#/)

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
    private string doUpload()
    {
        // Initialize variables
        string sSavePath;

        sSavePath = "images/";

        // Check file size (mustn’t be 0)
        HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        int nFileLen = myFile.ContentLength;
        if (nFileLen == 0)
        {
            //**************
            //lblOutput.Text = "No file was uploaded.";
            return null;
        }

        // Check file extension (must be JPG)
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpg")
        {
            //**************
            //lblOutput.Text = "The file must have an extension of JPG";
            return null;
        }

        // Read file into a data stream
        byte[] myData = new Byte[nFileLen];
        myFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, nFileLen);

        // Make sure a duplicate file doesn’t exist.  If it does, keep on appending an 
        // incremental numeric until it is unique
        string sFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myFile.FileName);
        int file_append = 0;
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename)))
        {
            file_append++;
            sFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName)
                             + file_append.ToString() + ".jpg";
        }

        // Save the stream to disk
        System.IO.FileStream newFile
                = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename),
                                           System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        newFile.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);
        newFile.Close();

        return sFilename;
    }
```