# how to read metadata of a file which is in amazon s3

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3

I would like to read the metadata of a file from the amazon s3. Is there any work around to achieve it.
For ex: My image is in amazon s3, I would like to read the 'date taken' metadata property of the image and return it to my application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to download the 'metadata' of the s3 object itself, you will need to perform a HEAD operation on the file in question.  That will return just the header information, which would include any metadata that had been included in the object.  Amazon S3 is very specific as to how metadata can be put into the header of an object.  Otherwise you will by default get things such as file size, server date, owner name, and few other pieces.

If you are trying to dig out metadata information that is actually part of the object itself, like inside the image file, then you are out of luck.  You will need to download the entire file first.  Not unless you can get what you need from a pre-defined byte range in the object, because then you could perform a GET operation and specify a byte-range that you wish to download.

AWS S3 HEAD documentation can be read here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html

Comment: Thanks for reply.This is what i came across.Can you please share the piece of code implemented in .net.As am new to this am unable to customize this in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Create the code to read metadata from any image file and test it anywhere just to see that the code works.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280948/reading-data-metadata-from-jpeg-xmp-or-exif-in-c-sharp) is one SO question on how to read metadata and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712752/read-image-file-metadata) is another SO question covering the same.

**Step 2:**
I see two options:

Suggestion 1:  Write a small program that runs on your amazon s3 implementing the code from step 1.  Call this small program from your application.  (Normal client-server implementation)

Suggestion 2:  Somehow give access to your application to do whataver it needs on the amazon s3 server so that the code from step 1 can reside in your application.  (I don't know how specifically to do this, but it should be possible)

Comment: The above steps doesn't work for me. I can able to retrieve metadata if the file is in my local system.I need to retrieve the metadata of the file which is in amazon without downloading the file.

Comment: @user1918612 See suggestion 1 of step 2 above.  You do not need to download any files in this case.

Comment: I have the same requirement.  I'd love to use exiftool but it doesn't take streaming data.